# Lopp through multidimensional array recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm learning about recursion. I have two dimensional array. I want to get numbers grather than 100

```
$arr=[923,100=>[123,158,12],111,12];
check_number($arr)

function check_number($arg){
        static $list=[];
        foreach($arg as $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                check_number($v);
            }
            if($v>100){
                $list[]=$v;
            }
          
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Result is an array:

```
 array:5 [▼
      0 => 923
      1 => 123
      2 => 158
      3 => array:3 [▼
        0 => 123
        1 => 158
        2 => 12
      ]
      4 => 111
```

I don't understand why key 3 contains nested array. Please give me some wxplanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a list, you are still running the next compare...

```
if($v>100){
    $list[]=$v;
}
```

at which point you are comparing an array against 100 and this will add in the array as well to `$list`.

Change that to an `elseif` and it will perform one or the other...

```
elseif($v>100){
    $list[]=$v;
}
```